# in FFMPEG, ":enable=between(t,5,10)" not starting at begining

Tags: ffmpeg

I have three inputs; two images and a folder of image squence.
Total length of image squence is 3 second.

```
ffmpeg
    -loop 1 -t 10 -i image1.jpg
    -loop 1 -t 10 -i image2.jpg
    -i png/out%d.png
    -filter_complex "
        [0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.15:offset=2.5[a];
        [a][2]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,5,5)'[video]
    " -map "[video]"
    -crf 30 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 918x1632 -r 12 -movflags +faststart -t 10 out.mp4
```

At the 5th second of out.mp4, image sequence is shown, but **not at its begining.** It seems that while rendering until the 5th second it was already started behind/invisibly.

How can I force FFMPEG to do it properly?